# Excel recordset encoding issue

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

I am having issue where recordset doesn't display words correctly.

```
Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim strCon As String
strCon = "Driver={Oracle in instantclient_21_6};Dbq=DAB;User Id=USER;Password=PASSWORD;"
Conn.Open (strCon)
```

This part is reading query which is written into txt file (txt file is in UTF-8 encoding):

```
fileSpec = "\\192.168.0.7\...\saldo_kartica.txt"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForReading)
caseInfo = objTS.ReadAll
caseInfo = Replace(caseInfo, "$ceid", caseID)
objTS.Close

cmdInfo.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText
cmdInfo.ActiveConnection = Conn
cmdInfo.CommandText = caseInfo

Set rsInfo = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rsInfo = cmdInfo.Execute
```

And values from **rsInfo** displays text like this:

[image]

but is should be displayed as:
"**Plaćeno**"

Comment: Please check if the data is read correct from the text file (see tristate values of [OpenTextFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method))

Comment: i tried with adding tristate argument, but the result is the same
`Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForReading, TristateTrue)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, basically txt files were using UTF-8 encoding.
I had to change file encoding to ANSI (simple save as using ANSI).

And changed connection string to this:

```
strCon = "Driver={Oracle in instantclient_21_6};Dbq=DAB;User Id=USER;Password=PASSWORD;FWC=T;"
```

I added **FWC=T** which forces SQL_WCHAR Support
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1182

**Solution was found overhere:**
https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/oracle-linked-table-display-unicode-chars-in-datasheet.185173/

Hope this will help to somebody else also. :)